# regular expression in ruby Regexp

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I'm using ruby 1.9.2

```
string = "asufasu isaubfusabiu safbsua fbisaufb sa {{hello}} uasdhfa s asuibfisubibas {{manish}} erieroi"
```

**Now I have to find {{anyword}}**

How many **times** it will come and the **name** with **curly braces.**

After reading [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)

I am using

```
/{{[a-z]}}/.match(string)
```

but it return nil everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apend a `*` to the `[a-z]` pattern to tell it to match any number of letters inside the `{`s, and then use `scan` to get all occurrences of the match in the string:

```
string.scan(/{{[a-z]*}}/)
=> ["{{hello}}", "{{manish}}"]
```

To get the number of times matches occur, just take the size of the resulting array:

```
string.scan(/{{[a-z]*}}/).size
=> 2
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd just like to add that if he needs to match upper and lowercase letters, he would need `[a-zA-Z]`.  Cheers!

Comment: @sean-hill Thanks! And I agree that `[a-zA-Z]` would probably be better, I just based my answer on the example which was all lowercase.

Comment: Instead of '\*', a '+' might be better, as the '\*' would also match the string '{{}}'.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression matching web application [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JBILNUnNSg) can be an incredibly helpful tool for doing realtime regular expression parsing.